# wicket6 websockets: namespaces or rooms

Tags: java, websocket, wicket

I could not find any possibiity to add namespaces/rooms in wicket native namespaces, is this only possible with another framwork like Atmosphere?

http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/nativewebsockets.html#nativewebsockets_3
these docs also dont present a method to do it

Answer (score 0):

Wicket Native WebSockets module provides a registry 
with all active connections - IWebSocketSettings#getWebSocketConnectionRegistry().
You can make an abstraction around it for topics, rooms, or 
whatever works best for your use case.